# Is there a possibility of adding a second condition, or an else clause to $/;$?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, rule

Let `tally=RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10];`

In the code below, I'm trying to output a list where each component $C_n=\sum^n_{i=1} \text{tally}_i / n$

The problem with my code below is that when `tally [[i]] == 0`, it doesn't change the component value as the formula above...

```
j = 0;
acceptanceplot = 
  ReplacePart[tally , {i_} /; tally [[i]] == 1 :> (j++/i)];
ListPlot[acceptanceplot[[1 ;; Length[tally]]]]
```

Is there a possibility of adding a second condition, or an else clause to $/;$? If possible, then I would just add the action `j/i`

Comment: Can you just string your clauses together with `&&` or `|`?

Comment: @CarlLange I'm not sure of what you're suggesting... Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: I don't think your way of constructing the new list in place of the old is a good idea: you assume that `ReplacePart` scans the elements in order, which is not specified in the manual and thus could change in different circumstances (e.g. parallelization).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[0]

tally = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10];

acceptanceplot = Accumulate[tally]/Range[Length[tally]];

ListPlot[acceptanceplot]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[0]

tally = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10^4];

acceptanceplot = Accumulate[tally]/Range[Length[tally]];

ListPlot[acceptanceplot]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Many thanks Bob. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this necessarily the best way to solve the problem at hand, but I think I understand what the OP means in terms of adding an "else clause" to `Condition` (`/;`). Now it isn't possible to modify the condition itself, but instead you can just add an extra replacement rule that fires whenever the first one doesn't:

```
acceptanceplot = ReplacePart[
  tally,
  {
   {i_} /; tally[[i]] == 1 :> j++/i,
   {i_} :> j/i
   }
]
```

If the first rule matches, that one will fire. Otherwise the less restrictive second rule will be applied.

Comment: Many thanks Sjoerd for your answer. +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
acceptance = Rest@FoldList[Plus, 0, tally]/Range[Length[tally]]
```

Comment: `Accumulate[tally]` is simpler than `Rest@FoldList[Plus, 0, tally]`, see @BobHanlon above.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Roman. ;)